# Textview not refreshed correctly

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with a textview. When I change the text value with settext, the old value doesn't desapear and the new value is drawn over. So after a few seconds, it's completely illegible. I don't know how to name this bug in english, it's why i post you the folowing screenshot (edit : i can't post it)

My source code :

```
public class AlarmActivity  extends Activity {

int tempsRestant;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_pad);

    startCountdown();
}

void startCountdown(){
    //final View view=findViewById(R.layout.activity_alarm_pad).getRootView();
    //final View view=((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.activity_alarm_pad)).getChildAt(0);

    final View view=this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    new CountDownTimer(59000, 1000) {
        TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             tempsRestant = (int)millisUntilFinished/1000;
            mTextField.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    mTextField.setText("00:" + tempsRestant);
                    ((View)mTextField.getParent()).invalidate();
                 }
             });
             //runOnUiThread(updateTimer());

         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("Systeme actif");
         }
      }.start();


}
}
```

I have tried a lot of things with .invalidate() (on the root View, on the parent view),  but i always have the same bug...

In fact, i don't understand if it's a problem with the view refresh or with the threads (the countdown thread).

Comment: try: textView.setText("");
then textView.setText("the new string goes here.");

Comment: I tried the settext(""), it was something i never tried, but I have the same bug.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you updating the `TextView` using `post`? Why not just: `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             tempsRestant = (int)millisUntilFinished/1000;
             mTextField.setText("00:" + tempsRestant);            
         }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, but I think the problem could be your device, I tried your code in Android 4.2.2 and 2.2 and it works:

```
mTextField.setText("");
mTextField.setText("00:" + tempsRestant);
((View) mTextField.getParent()).invalidate();
```

Comment: Same problem with my Galaxy S (Android 4.2.2). The emulator is running android 2.2